# three.js update light OrbitControls

Tags: javascript, three.js, light

I'm using `threejs` to display an object and `OrbitControls` to control movment of the scene with my mouse. My scene also inclues a `DirectionalLight`.

When the scene first renders, the `DirectionalLight` lights my object in the way I expect. However, when I modify the scene by rotating using my mouse the `DirectionalLight` source does not update and 'shine' the light from the new angle as I expect.

Can someone explain how I can update my scene so the light updates based on my rotation with `OrbitControls`?

Comment: Show your code. `controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera )` is used to control a camera, not a scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the relationship between the light direction and the camera view to remain constant, I suggest that you add the light to the CAMERA, not the SCENE.

So instead of, say `scene.add(dirLight)` you use `camera.add(dirLight)`

Comment: It works but now my light won't cast shadows anymore and I had to change the light position coz its now being reference w.r.t the cam.. Tried camera.castShadows = true without luck. Plus, I added a light helper really helps try to understand what happened.